# .NET cope with addition of optional parameters to unmanaged API

Tags: .net, vb.net, api, com, typelib

I'm working on providing reliable .NET interop for some software with an unmanaged API through COM for third-party developers.

Previously the software has only supported VBScript for third-party development, and because of this they've gotten used to being able to add new methods and optional parameters to fix functionality issues in the API.

In .NET however, adding an optional parameter constitutes a breaking change (as the method signature has altered). If the API was in .NET this could easily be solved by using overloaded methods, however because the API is unmanaged we're using a COM interface and therefore I cannot use overloads.

I don't have any influence of the API change policy

Things I've considered, but didn't get anywhere with:

- **Using Reflection Emit to add overloads at runtime** - 
  As far as I can see this can only be done if I dynamically create the *whole* assembly; and might not be possible given that the API is a typelib/COM rather than a true .NET assembly.
- **Catch and reroute invoke errors** - When the optional parameter is 'hit' the error has all the information needed to redirect the old method to the new one with the optional parameter. Unfortunately my understanding is that once an error is thrown you can't return.
- **Wrapping the typelib** - I will be able to know in advance when an API method is having an optional parameter added. I've therefore looked about to see if I could somehow add an overload to the typelib, or maybe wrap the whole typelib in a .NET proxy with overloaded methods included to transition between the pre-/post- optional parameter methods. But if it can be done, I really can't find a way of doing it.

All suggestions welcome- I'm getting pretty desperate here!

*n.b. .NET is fine with adding new methods, it's just the adding of optional parameters that is causing me trouble. Also, I am writing in VB.NET, but can happily code in C#, etc. if it makes things easier.*

Comment: It's not really my area of expertise, but doesn't Office interop use optional parameters in their API? You might look into how they handle it.

Comment: The Office PIA has far more resources than I and provides a different assembly for each Office version, which they maintain- something I doubt I'll be able to do without losing what little hair I've still got!

Comment: I have a project I have some unmanaged c++ code with a safe array of variants which I need to interop with vb.net. It originally had vbscript being used. I cannot even write a c++ wrapper because I do not know how to initialize the safearray to have an fFeatures of 2194 so the com code works. Hope your not in one of those scenario's with a safe array of variants (you will want to get away quick after you solve the problem). I almost would write in c# anything that requires a variant or write a c++ variant wrapper of your own. Too bad you have not listed any code I would have helped.

Answer (score 1):

Try declaring the function once for each parameter configuration using the Alias keyword.

```
Declare Function functionName1 Lib "libName" Alias "libFunctionName" (parameter configuration 1)
Declare Function functionName2 Lib "libName" Alias "libFunctionName" (parameter configuration 2)
...
```

Then call the appropriate function based on the parameters used in the call.

Comment: I think if I did that I would need to either author the whole typelibrary manually, or use Tlbimp and then declare functions in IL. To get what I need, however, functionName1 and functionName2 would have to be the same; or else the original API might as well have just added a new function itself, saving me some time. It's something I didn't think of though, so maybe it will push me in the right direction- thanks @xpda.